# Why has my profile stats on Careers decreased?

Tags: discussion, status-norepro, jobs, profile-page, views

A few days ago my profile at Careers was as follows:

[image]

But now the stats have decreased. I think it is 2 or 3 days after the previous image:

[image]

Why is it happening? Is it the fact that it is counted by a time frame, or has something invalidated the previous stats?

Comment: Are you sure you logged into the same account? I checked the DB and the stats match your first image. Code that renders this hasn't changed in over a year.

Comment: @DeanWard Well this is interesting. Considering what you said, I checked my marks again in Firefox, and it was the 2nd image, to make sure I checked it in chrome and it was the 1st image!

And by the way I am sure I am logged in the same account in both browsers.

Comment: Hmmm, that *is* strange. Can you try to logout, then back in on Firefox. Trying to eliminate some kind of output caching issue!

Comment: You were right, I re-logged in in Firefox, and now I see the 2nd image. Thank you. I think you were right about caching, but wondering how? Are you using some kind of client side caching?

Comment: A hard refresh would probably also have solved it. Caching headers that come from the ASP.NET `OutputCache` attribute are likely responsible here :)!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got why Firefox used to show me out-of-date stats.

In Firefox I have "Web Developer Toolbar" plugin, and in that I had set the option "Never Check For New Version Of The Page", that is why it used to show me the old one first time.

The exact location of the option is:

Disable > Disable Cache > Check For Newer Version Of The Page > Never Check For New Version Of The Page

Comment: That's one cunning Fox you got there... ;)