# Economics.SE's icon in HNQ doesn't have any identifying mark

Tags: bug, design, stackexchange.com, hot-questions, beta-sites

[image]

Isn't that bubble supposed to have something in it? Maybe an `E`?

For comparison, Programming Puzzles and Code Golf has `PCG`:

[image]

The HTML element looks just like any other:

```
<div class="favicon favicon-economics" title="Economics Stack Exchange"></div>
<div class="favicon favicon-codegolf" title="Programming Puzzles &amp; Code Golf Stack Exchange"></div>
```

The label does show up in stackexchange.com:

[image]

But not in Ask Ubuntu. Another example:

[image]

This happens consistently, after repeated refreshing (both <kbd>F5</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>F5</kbd>).

Comment: It should be the same as on the site itself, with "EC"  in the bubble.

Comment: I see it just fine, try to hard refresh. (CTRL+F5)

Comment: @ShadowWizard no luck.

Comment: If Firefox, it might be set to never take the latest version, see [this answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/269479/152859). Better use Chrome, or even IE.

Comment: @ShadowWizard Chrome, pretty recent stable: `46.0.2490.80`.

Comment: Try browsing directly to http://cdn.sstatic.net/economics/img/icon-48.png. what you see?

Comment: @ShadowWizard the Ec icon I got in http://stackexchange.com.

Comment: So it should be there. Something on your side is borked...

Comment: @ShadowWizard it doesn't happen in Firefox, but does happen in Chrome's private browsing. With and without extensions. Even after a minor version bump (to 46.0.2490.86).

Comment: Try debugging it from Developer Tools (F12) on Chrome. Go to "Network" tab and refresh, then check if there's resource that got blocked. (btw, I couldn't repro)

Comment: @AndrewT. nothing seemed to be blocked (all 304s, 200s, etc.) Say, what does http://meta.stackexchange.com/content/img/favicons-sprite32.png?v=f54d8c6b1d241ea87dd9ec8c740fc6a2 look like to you? Does it show a couple of empty boxes in the Es?

Comment: @ShadowWizard could you also check http://meta.stackexchange.com/content/img/favicons-sprite32.png?v=f54d8c6b1d241ea87dd9ec8c740fc6a2?

Comment: Yes, I saw 3 pairs of icons with blanks, and one of them just after "eB". But my Chrome seems to use 16px for HNQ, which has "EC" http://meta.stackexchange.com/content/img/favicons-sprite16.png

Comment: @AndrewT. that's the image supposed to provide all the HNQ favicons (using `background-image` and some positioning) from what I see on inspecting the element. Maybe you and ShadowWizard get different images.

Comment: I think the core issues are basically 1) some of sites don't have 32px sprites, and 2) why you get 32px sprite for HNQ, instead of 16px.

Comment: @AndrewT. (2) could possibly be because I usually browse at 175% zoom.

Comment: Oddly enough, I noticed this again today after months. And soon after, I get an upvote on this Q. I'd say this problem is not local to me.